# Merging existing git branch with formerly unknown SVN

Tags: svn, git, merge, branch, git-svn

My project I am working on is version controlled under SVN. I had to do a large number of refactorings. For this purpose I took my workspace and created a new git repository. Afterwards I made the refactorings and committed to my local git repository as often as possible, made branches etc..

Meanwhile someone made commits to the SVN. Now I would like to commit my changes also into the SVN. 
Adding the SVN via git-svn clone doesnt help, because the clone and the existing branches cant be merged (missing common ancestor) even if the tracked files are the same.

Is there a possibility to add a SVN link and/or create this ancestor?

Comment: Did you try doing "git svn rebase" before pushing your changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's sort of a dirty hack in this instance, but if you smash all the commits down using `rebase`, you could probably just `cherry-pick` the consolidated change.

UPDATE: Also, you might try using [`rebase`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) to move the root of the branch you did your refactoring on so that it branches from a branch that tracks the `git-svn` repo.

UPDATE 2: As ndim says, the `rebase` option you're looking for is probably `--onto`.

Comment: Probably a `git rebase ... --onto ...` would move the root.